# Organize two view types in a recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

With two view types, my recycler view can display a header content and the main content. I am lost on what the best way to organize these two in the adapter and thus have control on which view comes first. My current problem is having the header before the main content. Every time my header displays at the bottom which renders it useless.

```
//Declaration
    private static final int HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TOP_PICKS = 1;


//getViewtype

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position < mMainContentList.size()) {
            return MAIN_CONTENT;
        }
        return HEADER;

    }
//getItemCount

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {


        if (mHeaderItems == null) {
            return mMainContentList.size();
        } else {
            return mMainContentList.size() + 1;
        }


    }

What am I missing?
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what you are trying to archive. 
You want your header view to always stay on the top of the screen? please try to elaborate more and maybe add a sketch.

Comment: Yes..I have two layouts, one with a header and one to display the content(on a grid layout). The problem is my header always get's pushed to the bottom of the content instead of appearing at the top. Thank you

Comment: in your `getItemViewType` is wrong , use `position = 0`
            then `HEADER` otherwise `MAIN_CONTENT`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return HEADER;
        }
        return MAIN_CONTENT;
    }

@Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        if (mHeaderItems == null) {
            return mMainContentList.size();
        } else {
            return mMainContentList.size() + 1;
        }

    }

 @Override
  public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup pParent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater lLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(pParent.getContext());
    switch (viewType) {
      case HEADER:
        // inflate header view
          break;
      case MAIN_CONTENT:
           // inflate main content view
        break;

      default:
         // inflate main content view
    }
  }
```